# The most appropriate way to cite a mathematical notation

Tags: notation

I am writing a report with some mathematical formulae. I have a well-known book along side, very often, I just use the same notation as the paper. For instance, at the moment I write:

$((x_n, val_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in (\mathbb{X} \times (\text{Int}_{\mathbb{V} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}} (\text{defined at theorem 2.3.5 of the book})$
$\cup \{\{\bot_\text{bool}\}, \{\text{false}\}, \{\text{true}\}, \{\top_\text{bool}\}\}))^{|\mathbb{N}|}$
$\stackrel{\triangle}{=} (\mathbb{X} \times (\mathcal{E}^\sharp_{\textbf{interv}} (\text{defined at exercice 4.3.7 of the book})))$...

Could anyone tell me where I should put "defined at .... of the book" nicely, and make the mathematical formulae clean?

Thank you very much

Comment: The references need to be removed from the inside of formulas. If you intend the formulas to be actually read, the notation has to be explained ahead of time, in the report, with acknowledgement of where the notation was taken from. This can be bypassed only if it is very well-known to all likely readers. If the formulas are for decoration only, a reference, before the formulas, to a standard very available source may be enough.

Comment: In addition to what Andre said, It is also accepted to write something like 
 ... which leads to 

$$ Mathematical Expression$$

where $symbol$ means ... etc

Comment: In addition, another common (though often not quite true) way is to say ahead of time that "any unexplained notation can be found in ..."

Comment: Or you might want to include a list of notation(al conventions) before or after the main text, if you'll be using them a lot and saying "where `notation` is so-and-so" in the main text would be distracting. If the notation appears only once or twice in a page, a footnote might also be appropriate...

Comment: Thank you all for the comments

Comment: "In this section, we follow the notation used by Author (2001)."